# Escapar "/" com htaccess e/ou php

Tags: php, htaccess, mvc

Eu tenho um pequeno MVC feito por mim. Com urls Deste tipo `index.php?route=admin/produto/adicionar`, mas eu queria retirar `index.php?route=`, já consegui umas linhas de `.htaccess` que ficasse assim  `www.exemplo.com/admin/produto/adicionar`, o problema é que depois os ficheiros de css e js não são encontrados (`www.exemplo.com/public/public/js/404.php`):

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /wtj/public

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L]
```

Estrutura de ficheiros:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

configs/paths.php (aqui é onde defino os caminhos):

```
// folder name => path
return [
   "configs" => "../app/configs",
   "controllers" => "../app/controllers",
   "css" => "../public/css",
   "images" => "../public/images",
   "js" => "../public/js",
   "includes" => "../public/views/includes",
   "lang" => "../app/lang",
   "views" => "../public/views"
];
```

Real mensagem na consola, ficheiros a buscar:

> GET http://localhost/wtj/public/public/js/404.php
>
> GET http://localhost/wtj/public/public/css/cssAdmin/404.php

Que é o redirect programado para a minha página 404.

A página (rota) certa é assumida e vai ao controller/método certos, mas os ficheiros externos é dão problemas.

Comment: Olá, obrigado mas eu também tenho uma coisa desse tipo no meu projeto. Um ficheiro que retorna um array com os caminhos. Editei em cima

Comment: Testei agora e de facto funciona com paths absolutos :). Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema de não encontrar os caminhos está relacionado a relatividade dos paths. Ao invés de definir os caminhos em `/app/configs/paths.php` em forma de `array`, defina os caminhos na raiz em `/index.php` através de `DEFINE` assim poderá utilizar a constante em todo o escopo do projeto através de caminho absoluto.

**index.php** *(Em alguma linha antes da execução do seu MVC)*

```
DEFINE('PATH_CONFIGS', 'app/configs/');
DEFINE('PATH_CONTROLLERS', 'app/controllers/');
DEFINE('PATH_LANG', 'app/lang/');
DEFINE('PATH_CSS', 'public/css/');
DEFINE('PATH_IMG', 'public/images/');
DEFINE('PATH_JS', 'public/js/');
DEFINE('PATH_VIEWS', 'public/views/');
DEFINE('PATH_INCLUDES', PATH_VIEWS.'includes/');
```

Na hora de chamar a constante basta chamar assim:

```
echo PATH_CSS;
```

E se desejar continuar o caminho do path, basta concatenar a partir do caminho absoluto que já possui:

```
echo PATH_CSS . "cssAdmin/seu_arquivo.css";
```